# since 'fread' is buffred, is it necessary to fread data into memory and then use it?

Tags: c, linux, io, operating-system

I am using fopen/fread/fwrite/fseek on linux with gcc. is it necessary to allocate a memory buffer and use fread to read data sequentially into buffer before using the data?

Comment: How else can you use the data? If you mean you hope there's a file buffer in memory that gets filled by the `fopen` call before even the first `fread`, then no, there isn't.

Comment: If you really don't want to create your own buffer for this, you could try using `mmap` instead.

Comment: I think OP is referring to whether or not fread will request more bytes than requested and internally buffer it in user space, such that subsequent calls to fread don't require system calls, context, switch, etc.  The user provided buffer is just so that user code can have a copy of what they requested.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `fread` or the other file I/O functions in the C standard library, memory is buffered in several places.

- Your application allocates a buffer which gets passed to `fread`. `fread` copies data into your buffer, and then you can do what you want with it. *You are responsible for allocation/deallocation of this buffer.*
- The C library will usually create a buffer for every `FILE*` you have open. Data is read into this buffers in large chunks. This allows `fread` to satisfy many small requests without having to make a large number of system calls, which are expensive. This is what people mean when they say `fread` is buffered.
- The kernel will also buffer files that are being read in the disk cache. This reduces the time needed for the `read` system call, since if data is already in memory, your program won't have to wait while the kernel fetches it from the disk. The kernel will hold on to recently read files, and it may read ahead for files which are being accessed sequentially.

The C library buffer is allocated automatically when you open a file and freed when you close the file. You don't have to manage it at all.

The kernel disk cache is stored in physical memory that isn't being used for anything else. Again, you don't have to manage this. The memory will be freed as soon as it's needed for something else.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass a buffer (a buffer created by your code, malloced or local) to fread to pass the read data back to you. I don't know what do you exactly mean by saying "fread is buffered". Most 'C' library calls operate in this fashion. They will not return their internal storage (buffer or otherwise) to you and if they do, they will provide you a corresponding free/release functions.

Refer http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fread.html It has a very basic example also.

Comment: @Mickey: the libc does - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/setvbuf.html for how to control stdio buffering...

Comment: `fread()` is not a system call, it's part of the C library.  Typically the `FILE*` passed to it will have an internal buffer associated so it can read the file in large chunks even if you ask for the data one byte at a time.

Comment: @JeremyP, Agreed that fread is a 'C' library call and edited my answer also. : )

Answer (score 1):

With fread, yes, you have to allocate memory in your process and the system call will copy the data into your buffer.

In some specialised cases, you can handle data without copying it into userspace. See the [sendfile](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) system call, which copies data from one file descriptor to another directly. This can be used to transfer data from a file to a network socket without excessive copying.